# Recursions With Integers (Very Basic)

Tags: java, recursion, int

I am currently taking a HS course on java, so I am a novice at java to say the least. Right now, for my own use, I am writing a program to take a 2 digit number, and then add up it and all the odd numbers before it till 1. I have the Scanner, calculating whether the number is odd or even, and the runner methods done already(the basic bit), but am a bit confused on the logic. I am trying to use a recursion, and do this code, but am a bit stuck. It would be helpful if you could point me in the right direction, without giving the whole code away. Thanks, - A Novice Programmer

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    MathRecursion tester =  new MathRecursion();
    tester.Method1Runner();
}

public void Method1Runner()
{
GetIntM1();
OddOrEven();
System.out.println("\n\n");
}

public void GetIntM1()
{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("\n\n\nEnter a 2 digit integer: ");
    twoDig = kb.nextInt();
}

public void OddOrEven()
{
    if (twoDig % 2 == 0)
    {
        //This is even method
        Method1a(twoDig);
    }
    else 
    {
        //This is odd method
        Method1b(twoDig);
    }
}
public int Method1a(int a)
{
    //if (a = 1)
    int result = 0;
    while (a<=b) 
    {
        result+=a;
        a++; 
    }   
    System.out.println("The sum of all numbers is "+result); 
}
```

Comment: please show the code you wrote, explain where your failing etc -  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am so sorry, I did not realize I did not copy paste my code! Will do an edit to fix that. So sorry for the waste of your time.

Comment: Ok, just updated with the code. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Did read the question, did read the code, and I don't understand what recursion you are talking about. Maybe you should post input, expected output and the process to go from input to output.

Comment: Also note that if a number is odd (even resp.), subtracting 2 from it gives you an odd (even resp.)

Comment: The code you posted is not complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need recursion. [The sum of the first `n` odd numbers is `n*n`.](http://www.beatthegmat.com/formula-for-consecutive-even-odd-integers-t17241.html)

The number of odd numbers before a number `x` is `floor(x/2)` or in Java `(int) x/2` or if `x` is an `int`, just `x/2`.

So the expression in Java that gives you "a 2 digit number, and then add up it and all the odd numbers before it till 1" where the number is stored in `int x` is:

```
x + (x/2) * (x/2)
```

or simplified:

```
x + x*x/4
```

Comment: I know how to do it without recursion, but I have to use a recursion. Any tips?